# why foodModule not defined error? Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i have been separating it out the route file. but it giving the module not defined error. Can anyone guess the problem?

main.js

```
var foodModule = angular.module('scratchpad',['ui.router','ngResource']);
```

route.js

```
console.log('route.js included successfully');


foodModule.config(function($stateProvider,$httpProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('home',{
    url:'/home',
    templateUrl:'templates/food.html',
        controller:'addUserController'
  })
  .state('scratchpad',{
        url:'/scratchpad',
        templateUrl:'templates/scratchpad.html',
        controller:'scratchListController'
    })
    .state('addNewScratch',{
        url:'/addNewScratch',
        templateUrl:'templates/addNewScratch.html',
        controller:'addScratchController'
    })
    .state('scratchpad.viewScratch',{
        url:'/scratchpad/:id/view',
        templateUrl:'templates/viewScratch.html',
        controller:'viewScratchController'
    })
}).run(function($state){
    $state.go('home');
});
```

Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: foodModule is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't cache your angular module, you're leaking things into global scope.
Instead do this:

for main.js:

```
//Just declare the module
angular.module('scratchpad',['ui.router','ngResource']);
```

for the route js... do it like so:

```
angular.module('scratchpad')
  .config(function($stateProvider,$httpProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('home',{
    url:'/home',
    templateUrl:'templates/food.html',
        controller:'addUserController'
  })
  .state('scratchpad',{
        url:'/scratchpad',
        templateUrl:'templates/scratchpad.html',
        controller:'scratchListController'
    })
    .state('addNewScratch',{
        url:'/addNewScratch',
        templateUrl:'templates/addNewScratch.html',
        controller:'addScratchController'
    })
    .state('scratchpad.viewScratch',{
        url:'/scratchpad/:id/view',
        templateUrl:'templates/viewScratch.html',
        controller:'viewScratchController'
    })
}).run(function($state){
    $state.go('home');
});
```

better yet, wrap those inside [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

See [John Papa's Angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) for better explanation...

I suggest bundling them as well using gulp / grunt so they are in the right order and serve the bundled instead.  There is no guarantee that main js will be executed first unless you are using module loader like require / system js.  Been bitten with something similar to this in IE before.  Perhaps [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/) can shed a light on the issue but nothing that good build system can't fix so yeah...

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible you put the order like :-

```
<script src="route.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

It should be like :-

```
 <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="route.js"></script>
```

Comment: No not really i followed the second order only

`code:
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/routes.js"></script>`